# Closing another browser tab

Tags: browser

If I send a user to a mobile app store (my app's page), is there any way I can close that tab automatically after the user downloads my app?

Comment: i think you might be missing some tags

Comment: an option would possibly be to open a web browser inside of your app, and handle closing it that way.

Comment: I still don't see how I'll know when to close that window. Wouldn't there have to be an event that fires after the mobile site has pushed the app to the phone? Then I would subscribe to that event and close the window when the event fires. I don't think it's possible to close someone else's window when I have no control over it. I could be wrong, but I still don't see how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can always try this,
If you are displaying options using JavaScript ,Just add

```
window.close();
```

as last line of script

or place separate  JavaScript like

```
function  CloseWindow() {
 window.close();
 }
```

and call it from Button `onClick (HTML--> OnClick="CloseWindow()"/ASP-->this.btnTest.Attributes.Add("OnClick","CloseWindow()"); )`

Also you can store the access point to child window (pop up window) at parent (opener window)

```
var child = window.open();
```

Then you can close that pop up window from parent side

```
child. close();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have to be called after the user has finished installing the mobile app on their phone (or at least pushing it from the app store)? How would I know when that is complete?